# How do I install Android SDK Platform-Tools 24.0.0?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I'm following the guide for setting up the Android N Preview https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html

In "Update or Create a Project" Google says I need to have 24.0.0 platform tools.

> Just be sure that you've updated your project to use Android SDK Build
>   Tools 24.0.0 and Android SDK Platform-Tools 24.0.0.

I have installed the new SDK Platform: Android 6.X (N), API Level 24, Revision 1. However when I open SDK Tools the only Android SDK Platform-Tools version is 23.1.

[image: Android Studio Platform-Tools 23.1]

I have updated my `build.gradle` for Android 24 and for Jack and Java 8 ([see](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html)).

Everything works great on Android 24 simulator but crashes on a device or simulator running Android 22/23 (less than 24) with the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
>   stream()Ljava/util/stream/Stream; in class Ljava/util/ArrayList; or
>   its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.ArrayList' appears in
>   /system/framework/core-libart.jar)

I suspect the cause is having SDK Platform-Tools version 23.1.0 instead of 24.0.0 but if there is another solution i'd be happy to hear it.

### Edit

Installing platform tools 24.0.0 rc1 did not fix the crash.
I'm not sure what else to try given that I have followed all the instructions to setup the preview and the Jack compiler.

Comment: SDK Platform-Tools has nothing to do with the build (you have the latest version)

Comment: Do you have Android SDK Build-Tools 24? Just expand that first option under SDK tools and it should be under there.

Comment: Yes, I have Android SDK Build-Tools 24 (along with 23.0.2 and 23.0.3). `build.gradle` is using `compileSdkVersion 24`

Comment: In the standalone SDK Manager, you will find what you want as rev `24 rc1` in the "Tools (Preview Channel)" area.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare, I was able to install the 24.0.0 platform tools but unfortunately that didn't fix the `NoSuchMethodError`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but crashes on a device or simulator running Android 22/23 (less than 24) with the following error

[`java.util.stream.Stream` was added in API Level 24](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/stream/Stream.html). This class cannot be used on older devices.

Certain Java 8 features, like lambda expressions, may work on older devices, but not classes that were introduced in Android N.

Comment: I took the following to mean lambda and streams are available in earlier version "To test lambda expressions, method references, and type annotations on earlier versions of Android, go to your build.gradle file, and set compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 23 or lower. You will still need to enable the Jack toolchain to use these Java 8 features."     Source: https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html#supported-features

Comment: That does make sense in hindsight, thank you for explaining

Answer (score 2):

Just select the show package details and then you can find all the versions. Refer to the attached image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you have Android Studio 2.1

Launch the standalone SDK manager.

From there Android N API 24 should be available to install

Answer (score 0):

Your API level 24 app runs OK with Android 24 (virtual) device but doesn't work with pre-24 device - so everything is exactly as one would expect.

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything to what was already said by CommonsWare. Please do not post answers that just repeat others. Thank you!

Comment: It was indeed already said that 'class was added in API Level 24 so the class cannot be used on older devices', however future readers might benefit from clarifying there was a wrong reasoning behind the question. Because OP said: 'Everything works on API 24 device but doesn't work on API 22/23 device, *so I suspect I should build the app with API 24* to make it work.'. While in fact the correct reasoning would be something as: 'It works on API 24 device but doesn't work on API 22/23 device, so I suspect I should build the app with an older API (22/23) to make it work with an older device.'.